# Display Field value on same record with LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

JS:

```
    import { LightningElement, wire, api} from 'lwc';
import {getRecord, getFieldValue} from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';

import AUTH_CONTACT from '@salesforce/schema/Opportunity.Authorised_Contact_Name__c';
import AUTH_NUMBER from '@salesforce/schema/Opportunity.Authorised_Contact_Phone__c';

const fields = [
    AUTH_CONTACT,
    AUTH_NUMBER
];

export default class GetFieldTest2 extends LightningElement{
   @api recordId;

    @wire(getRecord, {recordId: '$recordId', fields: fields})
    opportunity;

    get authName() {
        return getFieldValue(this.opportunity.data, AUTH_CONTACT);
    }

    get authNumber() {
        return getFieldValue(this.opportunity.data, AUTH_NUMBER);
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<template>
<div class="slds-theme_alert-texture slds-box_small">
        <strong>Permission To Speak</strong>
    <p>There is permission to speak to another individual, see below for details</p>
        <div class= "slds-var-m-around_medium">
            <p>Authourised Name : {authName}</p>
            <p>Authourised Contact Phone : {authNumber} </p>
            <p>Id: {recordId}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I'm trying to display some values on an Opportunity with an LWC - these values are from the same record

The ID of the record is showing properly but the other 2 fields aren't showing on the LWC
How can i get the values to show?

Thanks

Comment: Code looks ok, do you see any errors in chrome's developer console?

Answer (score 0):

Please make below change in your code in wire adapter.

```
export default class GetFieldTest2 extends LightningElement{


@api recordId;

 @wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields })
    opportunity;

    get authName() {
        return getFieldValue(this.opportunity.data, AUTH_CONTACT);
    }

    get authNumber() {
        return getFieldValue(this.opportunity.data, AUTH_NUMBER);
    }
}
```

Please refer this [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/reference_get_field_value) also. It might give you more clarity.

Comment: What did you change? Your snippet looks exactly like op's.

Comment: i have made changes in wire method. 
given :- 
@wire(getRecord, {recordId: '$recordId', fields: fields})

changed to 
@wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields })

In the documents also, it is given in this format. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/reference_get_field_value